# how i can use NSPopUP Button in swift?

Tags: swift, nspopupbutton

I am new to iOS development. Please tell me how to use NSPopUp button in swift. I want to create a popup menu using NSPopUp button.

```
Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: Do you mean `UIPopoverController`?

Comment: NSPopUpButton is an OS X class, not iOS.